# Weird animations when list rows appear in a list that is in a sheet when the presentation detent goes to a larger one

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

This is what I am referring to. I have attached the video demonstrating this issue in the link below:
https://streamable.com/b1ba5e

I am not sure why but when I switch to a larger presentation detent for a sheet, the rows in the list gets a weird sweeping from the right animation at the bottom when they become visible.

How do I prevent this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap Me") {
            showingSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            List(0..<1000) {
                Text("\($0)")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(180), .medium, .large])
        }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `.padding(.bottom, 0)` (seriously) to the list. I don't see this effect anymore after doing that. Seems like yet another SwiftUI bug to me.